# xquery optional where statements

Tags: xpath, xquery

In Xquery 3.1 I am processing the variable parameters from a form to search for matching XML documents. The XML documents look like this:

```
<listBibl xml:id="TC0001" type="collection">
  <bibl>
    <title type="collection">Bonum universale de apibus</title>
    <affiliation corresp="dominican"/>
    <author nymRef="thomas_cantipratensis"/>
    <location corresp="flanders"/>
    <othercontent>....</othercontent>
  </bibl>
</listBibl>
```

The user can submit *optional* parameters against `xml:id`, `affiliation`, `author`, and `location`, and they can be parameters with multiple values (sequences).

If the user were to submit *all* parameters, the query might look like:

```
for $c in $mycollection//listBibl[@xml:id=($params_id)]
where $c/affiliation[@corresp=($params_affil)] 
       and $c/author[@nymRef=($params_author)]
       and $c/location[@corresp=($params_location)]
return $c
```

But the user may leave certain parameters empty, effectively making each `where` statement optional.

The only solution I can currently put together is to have a series of `if...then...else` statements which account for each permutation of parameters.

Is there any way in Xpath or Xquery to account for the parameters being empty with a `wildcard` of some sort? In pseudo code, where `*` represents a wished-for wildcard:

```
 where $c/affiliation[if ($params_affil) 
                      then @corresp=($params_affil)
                      else @corresp=* ]
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use predicates of the form

```
[$params_affil=("", @corresp)]
```

which matches if $params_affil is either a zero-length string or equal to `@corresp`. And make zero-length-string (rather than empty sequence) the default if the parameter is not supplied.

Alternatively if the default for an absent parameter is (), use

```
[empty($params_affil) or $params_affil=@corresp)]
```

If that gets too repetitive, put the logic in a user-declared function.

Comment: I didn't realize passing an empty parameter would effectively return "everything"!

Comment: GIven an expression `B[P]`, if `P` is true for every item in `B`, then the value of the expression is the same as `B`.

Comment: @MichaelKay so putting it altogether like this should work, right?

```
$mycollection//listBibl[empty($params_id) or ./@xml:id=($params_id)][empty($params_affil) or ./affiliation/@corresp=($params_affil)]
[empty($params_author) or ./author/@nymRef=($params_author)]
[empty($params_location) or ./location/@corresp=($params_location)]
```

Comment: Yes, that looks OK.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can always declare and use your own function as a predicate expression e.g.

```
declare function local:check-item($item as node(), $values as item()*) as xs:boolean
{
    if (exists($values))
    then $item = $values
    else true()
};

....
where $c/affiliation[local:check-item(@corresp, $params_affil)]
```

Comment: I don't think I understand how this function actually works - if the returned result is `true` how does that returned result function in the predicate?

Comment: @jbrehr, inside of a predicate you are always dealing with a boolean value, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-filter-expression stating "For each item in the input sequence, the result of the predicate expression is coerced to an xs:boolean value, called the predicate truth value, as described below. Those items for which the predicate truth value is true are retained, and those for which the predicate truth value is false are discarded". So the function returning `true` in the case that the `$values` argument is an empty sequence ensures that the `affiliation`s in this case are selected

Comment: @jbrehr, Michael Kay's answer gives you a more compact expression but the `if else` I used in the function was meant to be closer to your pseudo code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Given the same dataset, would the compact expression result in more processing efficiency?